# Find and replace by a single dot several series of two dots attached to the end of words

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, macros, find-and-replace, wildcards

I want to replace every series of two dots in a document by a single dot, excluding the cases where there are three dots in a row, i.e., the written ellipsis `(...)`.

Yet, the series of two dots always appear attached to the end of a word, while a space follows them, for example

The word abbreviation can be abbreviated as `abbr..`. Yet, its plural should `not...` or should it?

How could I do this using the Find & Replace tool, or a macro?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/download/):

```
#singleInstance force

`::

; Copy text if necessary
if (clipboard = "") {
    send ^c
    clipWait .33
    if errorLevel {
        send ^c
        clipWait .33
        if errorLevel
            exit
    }
}

; Replace all instances of (..) with (.)
stringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, .., ., all
sleep 33

; Restore all prior instances of (...)
stringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, .., ..., all
sleep 33

exitApp
```

Steps:

1. [Create/run](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm#s12) the above script.
2. Highlight/copy the text you want to modify.
3. Press <kbd>`</kbd>

Your clipboard will now contain text with all instances of `..` replaced with `.` without affecting instances of `...`